# Is it possible to reject excessively large queries on specific views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, denial-of-service

I'm working with MS-SQL Server, and we have several views that have the potential to return enormous amounts of processed data, enough to spike our servers to 100% resource usage for 30 minutes straight with a single query (if queried irresponsibly).

There is absolutely no business case in which such huge amounts of data would need to be returned from these views, so we'd like to lock it down to make sure nobody can DoS our SQL servers (intentionally or otherwise) by simply querying these particular views without proper `where` clauses etc.

Is it possible, via triggers or another method, to check the `where` clause etc. and confirm whether a given query is "safe" to execute (based on thresholds we determine), and reject the query if it doesn't meet our guidelines?

Or can we configure the server to reject given execution plans based on estimated time-to-completion etc.?

Comment: Are end-users writing ad-hoc SQL queries?  Or are you worried about developers who write poor code?

Comment: @JamesL. The latter. :) Buggy code, in particular.

Comment: It seems like you should focus on your QC processes to ensure that poor code doesn't impact your database, instead of trying to build a pre-query analyzer to block queries that may be legit, but may have a longer estimated runtime because statistics are out-of-date (for example).  The problem isn't limited to querying views, developers might write a bad query against tables that performs poorly too, or even worse, a Cartesian product.  It seems you are solving the wrong problem.  The best place to catch bad code and performance problems is in the dev/QC cycle.

Comment: Would it be worth it change the view in question to a function?

Comment: @JamesL. Sure, that's also in the works, but unfortunately we have to convince many people across multiple levels of authority to improve the QC processes for their teams, and that simply isn't going to happen soon enough. We'd like to explore the possibility of protecting the databases directly in the interim, as an added security measure.

Comment: @Mikey That's actually a pretty good idea. Lemme do some testing and talk to a few of my colleagues about it, and I'll see if we can come to a consensus.

Comment: @Giffyguy: Make sure those functions are *in-line Table-valued*, or you will create worse problems. I also recommend migrating to http://dba.stackexchange.com/'

Answer (score 4):

One potential way to reduce the overall cost of certain queries coming from a certain group of people is to use the resource governor.  You can throttle how much CPU and/or memory is used up be a particular user/group.  This is effective if you have a "wild west" kind of environment where some users submit bad queries that eat your resources alive.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=sql.110).aspx).

Another thing to consider is to set your MAXDOP (max degree of parallelism) to prevent any single query from taking all of the available CPU threads.  That is, if MAXDOP is 1, then any query can only take 2 CPU threads to process.  This is useful to prevent a large query from letting smaller quick ones processing.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx).

Comment: Oh yes big help.  Slow it down so it holds locks longer.

Comment: Do you have constructive feedback for me?  These techniques have improved other people's issues around similar circumstance.  I didn't see that the OP had lock blocking issues.  He talked about 100% resource usage.  I actually think these are very useful features.

Comment: A lock never causes resource issues?  Slowing things down to make them go faster is rarely a good strategy.  That is constructive feedback.   Really you think the 30 minute queries are just that way?  No lock contention going on?

Comment: Of course locks cause contention.  Select queries cause share level locks.  They are compatible with other share level locks.  When you get CXPACKET and SOS scheduler yield wait types, nothing's getting through.  This is a global change and considered good practice by many (MAXDOP).  If views are causing angst, I typically tune the most painful/lowest hanging fruit.  If there are systemic issues, then system-wide changes aren't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: But OP is not asking about tuning specific view nor one query blocking  another.  OP is worried about total load.  Throttling via resource governor or MAXDOP does not reduce the overall load.  All it does it keep a query around longer and that is never a good thing relative to overall load.  If query optimizer wants to take all CPU and all memory to get it done then that is the right thing to do.  If the server is idle let the query optimizer get things done.   If it is loaded let the query optimizer throttle (load level).

Answer (score 3):

Kind of hacky but put a top x in every view

You cannot enforce it at the SQL side but on the app size they could use a TimeOut.  But if they lack QC they probably lack the discipline for TimeOut.  If you have some queries going 30 minutes they are probably setting a value longer than the default.

Comment: I like this idea, I think I would just need to figure out a way to notify the queryer via a message/warning of some sort. It's too bad you can't write triggers after select. Perhaps if we converted the views to inline table-valued functions, we could handle the notifications there - though that isn't really an 'inline' operation per se.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced about Blam's top X in each view. Without a corresponding ORDER BY clause the data will be returned in an indeterminate order. There may benefits to CDC's MAXDOP suggestion. Not so much for itself, but for the other queries that want to run at the same time.

I'd be inclined to look at moving to stored procedures. Then you can require input parameters and evaluate them before the query gets run in earnest. If, for example, a date range is too big, you can restrict it. You should also find out who is running the expensive query and what they really need. Seems like they might benefit from some ETL. Just some ideas.